# Umvue and efficiency

Tags: umvue

Considering the class of unbiased estimator:

> If an estimator is efficient then it is an umvue
>
> But if an estimator is an umvue it is not true in general that it is also effcient

What hypothesis is this second statement lacking in order to make it true?

**my guess**: the umvue has the minimum variance but only **uniformly**, while efficiency means that has the minimum variance more generally.

But then what generally would mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an UMVU estimator does not reach the Rao-Cramer lower bound, it is not efficient.

Comment: Can you make a simple example on how it cannot reach the c.r. Lower bound?

Comment: Also if the umvue is not efficient, then would it mean that an efficient estimator does not exist (inside or outside the class of unbiased estimator)?

Comment: The classic example is for the variance in the normal distribution. The sample variance is the umvu estimator, but it is not efficient.

Comment: to your second comment, yes,

Comment: Are you sure the C-R lower bound always can be reached?